# replaceDialog() inside cancelAction

Tags: botframework

I am using a LUIS recognizer in my code to trigger dialogs. In one of my dialogs ('search') I would like to invoke the 'help' dialog when the user types 'cancel'. I was hoping to achieve this through the onSelectAction within the cancelAction. However I am getting an error:

```
(node:42184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Dialog[BotBuilder:help] not found.
```

However I do have a 'help' dialog in my code. Is this happening because the 'help' is not in the dialog stack? Any pointers on how to debug this would be much appreciated.

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var restify = require('restify');

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});
// Create connector and listen for messages
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.replaceDialog('search');
});

bot.dialog('help', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        session.send('Help dialog');
    }
]);

bot.dialog('search', [
  function (session, args, next) {
    builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What would you like to search?');
  }
]).cancelAction('cancelAction', 'Ok, cancelling your search', {
  matches: /^cancel$/,
  onSelectAction: (session, args, next) => {
    session.replaceDialog('help', args);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the comment of `replaceDialog`:

> Ends the current dialog and starts a new one its place. The parent dialog will not be resumed until the new dialog completes.

According the comment in source code of `onSelectAction` action:

```
/**
  ...
     * It's important to note that this is not a waterfall and you should call `next()` if you 
     * would like the actions default behavior to run. 
     */
    onSelectAction?: (session: Session, args?: IActionRouteData, next?: Function) => void;
```

it seems that we need to call `next()` first, which can remove the `botbuilder` library, this action will change the library to `*`.

So, try following:

```
bot.dialog('search', [
  function (session, args, next) {
    builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What would you like to search?');
  }
]).cancelAction('cancelAction', 'Ok, cancelling your search', {
  matches: /^cancel$/,
  onSelectAction: (session, args, next) => {
    next();
    session.replaceDialog('help', args);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your willingness to help. I have edited my question to include the complete code. Can you please verify?